# What mathematics principles or law I infringed assuming this simple equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I now that this is wrong, but why?

$$3x\log(2)+2x\log(3) = \log(6)$$
$$3x\log(2)+2x\log(3) = \log(2*3)$$
$$3x\log(2)+2x\log(3) = 1\log(2)+1\log(3)$$
$$3xA+2xB = 1A+1B$$
$$3x+2x = 1+1$$
$$x = {2 \over 5}$$

Comment: Try to write a step between the second and third line (where the $\log$s disappear) and see if you spot the error.

Comment: $ab+cd=0$ does not imply $a+c=0$

Comment: From $3x\log (2) + 2x\log (3) = 1\log (2) + 1\log (3)$, you should have divided both sides by the same number. You might be thinking of $\dfrac{3x\log (2) + 2x\log (3)}{\log (2) + \log (3)}$, but this does not simplify to $3x+2x$.

Comment: In vector spaces this reasoning can work, if the linear combination is of orthogonal vectors. For example in the complex numbers, if $2+7i=p+qi$ you can conclude $p=2, q=7$. In your case you're sitting in the real numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have divided $(3x\log 2)$ and $(1 \log 2)$ by $(\log 2)$ and at the same time divided $(2x\log 3)$ and $(1\log 3)$ by $(\log 3)$ – but that does not make any sense. You *may* divide both sides of an equation by the same (non-zero) value, but you may not divide arbitrary subexpressions.

Here is a simpler example of your routine, hopefully it makes it clear what went wrong.

Let's take a simple equality:
$$3\cdot 100 + 2\cdot 200 = 1\cdot 100 + 3\cdot 200$$
This is obviously true, as both sides equal $700$.

Now, let's reduce hundreds, as you did with logarithms:
$$3 + 2 = 1 + 3$$
$$5 = 4$$

Does the resulting equality hold...?

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. The wrong step was in the division of both equations, hidden by the wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, leaving the common $x$ aside, $\dfrac{3\log (2) + 2\log (3)}{\log (2) + \log (3)}$ or $\dfrac{3A+2B}{A+B}$ is definitely not $3+2=5$. It is a weighted sum of $3$ and $2$, and so $$2<\dfrac{3\log (2) + 2\log (3)}{\log (2) + \log (3)}<3.$$

(For positive $A$ and $B$ anyway)